# Adding extra fields to django-registration form

Tags: python, django, forms, models, django-registration

I have a model called "Organization" that I've setup as a User profile and I would like to have the fields from the "Organization" model show up on the registration page. How do I go about doing this with django-registration.

```
# models.py
class Organization(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
    logo = models.ImageField(upload_to='organizations')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, unique=True)

    # more fields below etc.

# settings.py
AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE = 'volunteering.organization'
```

Answer (score 6):

The easiest way to do this would be [tested on `django-registration` 0.8]:

**Somewhere in your project, say forms.py in your organization app**

```
from registration.forms import RegistrationForm
from django.forms import ModelForm
from models import Organization

class OrganizationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Organization

RegistrationForm.base_fields.update(OrganizationForm.base_fields)

class CustomRegistrationForm(RegistrationForm):
    def save(self, profile_callback=None):
        user = super(CustomRegistrationForm, self).save(profile_callback=None)
        org, c = Organization.objects.get_or_create(user=user, \
            logo=self.cleaned_data['logo'], \
            name=self.cleaned_data['name'])
```

**Then in your root urlconf [but above the regex pattern that includes `registration.urls` and assuming that regex is `r'^accounts/'`] add:**

```
from organization.forms import CustomRegistrationForm

urlpatterns += patterns('',
    (r'^accounts/register/$', 'registration.views.register',    {'form_class':CustomRegistrationForm}),
)
```

Obviously, you can also [create a custom backend](http://docs.b-list.org/django-registration/0.8/backend-api.html), but IMHO this is way easier.

Comment: i keep getting this error: register() takes at least 2 non-keyword arguments (1 given).

Comment: This is due differing versions of django-registration. I believe he did a rewrite with 0.8.

Answer (score 2):

The best way would be to create in the app where you have Organization a file (say, "forms.py"), and do this:

```
from registration.forms import RegistrationForm
from forms import *
from models import Organization

class RegistrationFormWithOrganization(RegistrationForm):
    organization_logo = field.ImageField()
    organization_name = field.CharField()

def save(self, profile_callback = None):
    Organization.objects.get_or_create(user = self.cleaned_data['user'],
                                       logo = self.cleaned_data['organization_logo'],
                                       name = self.cleaned_data['organization_name'])

    super(RegistrationFormWithOrganization, self).save(self, profile_callback)
```

And then in your base URLs, override the existing URL to registration, and add this form as your the form to use:

```
 form organization.forms import RegistrationFormWithOrganization

 url('^/registration/register$', 'registration.views.register', 
     {'form_class': RegistrationFormWithOrganization}),
 url('^/registration/', include('registration.urls')),
```

Remember that Django will use the first URL that matches the regexp, so will match your call and not django-registration's.  It will also tell registration to use your form, not its own.  I've skipped a lot of validation here (and, probably, the derivation of the user object... if so, go read the source code to registration to see where it comes from), but this is definitely the right track to get a few things into the page with a minimum amount of effort on your part.

Comment: This would not work because (a) `RegistrationForm` does not have a `user` field, so the `self.cleaned_data['user']` will throw a `KeyError` exception; (b) You need a `User` object to create an `Organization` object, and you won't get this until you call `RegistrationForm.save` which returns the newly created `user` object. Please see my answer for an alternative solution.

Comment: @SimonKagwi i used your answer but i keep getting this error :TypeError at /accounts/register/
register() takes at least 2 non-keyword arguments (1 given)

Answer (score 1):

Modify the code as below and try again

```
urlpatterns += patterns('',
(r'^accounts/register/$', 'registration.views.register',    {'form_class':CustomRegistrationForm,'backend': 'registration.backends.default.DefaultBackend'}),
```

)

Answer (score 0):

"Previously, the form used to collect data during registration was expected to implement a save() method which would create the new user account. This is no longer the case; creating the account is handled by the backend, and so any custom logic should be moved into a custom 
backend, or by connecting listeners to the signals sent during the registration process."

Details:

more info can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2601487/django-registration-django-profile-using-your-own-custom-form/2687377#2687377)