# django-registration 1.0 saving custom user fields

Tags: django, django-registration

I've been trying to use django-registration with a custom User, but cannot get past one small problem. I added one additional field to User which DISPLAYS on the register form, but fails to SAVE any data. Here's the relevant codes:

models.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db import models

class eduuser(AbstractUser):
   USER_TYPE_CHOICES = (
      #Choices
)
   user_type = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=USER_TYPE_CHOICES)
```

forms.py

```
from registration.forms import RegistrationForm
from django import forms
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import eduuser

class eduuserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = eduuser
        fields = ('user_type',)

RegistrationForm.base_fields.update(eduuserForm.base_fields)


class CustomRegistrationForm(RegistrationForm):
    def save(self, profile_callback=None):
        user = super(CustomRegistrationForm, self).save(profile_callback=None)
        edu, c = eduuser.objects.get_or_create(user=user, \
            user_type=self.cleaned_data['user_type'])
```

urls.py

```
from posts.forms import CustomRegistrationForm

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^accounts/register/$', RegistrationView.as_view(
        form_class=CustomRegistrationForm)),
)
```

The problem seems to be in the forms.py file, specifically the "CustomRegistrationForm" class. That idea came from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5122542/adding-extra-fields-to-django-registration-form) post, which was for django-registration 0.8.

Anyways, does anyone have any idea of how to save extra custom user fields with django-registration 1.0? Any ideas/suggestions/solutions help!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I figured out a solution, albeit a rough one. If anyone else is having similar issues in regards to adding & saving extra user fields to the registration page provided by django-registration 1.0, hopefully this will be of some help... (although I can't guarantee this will actually work for you)

1) Create a new user model in an app, adding an extra fields you please:

```
# posts/models.py
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class eduuser(AbstractUser):
    # Created USER_TYPE_CHOICES, omitted here due to length
    user_type = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=USER_TYPE_CHOICES)
```

2) Add the user model to your settings file. My app happens to be called "posts" so my user model is:

```
# appName/settings.py
AUTH_USER_MODEL = "posts.eduuser"
```

3) Adjust django-registration to deal with a new user model. I made the changes seen [here](https://bitbucket.org/prjts/django-registration/commits/ba31fc3053bfca7eb7a19d912882e50e295adc55). This should not affect the functionality of django-registration, if you happen to be using it with another project.

4) Add the extra field(s) to the form:

```
# posts/forms.py
from registration.forms import RegistrationForm
from django import forms
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import eduuser


class eduuserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """
    Get extra 'user_type' field to add to form for django-registration
    """
    class Meta:
        model = eduuser
        fields = ('user_type',)

RegistrationForm.base_fields.update(eduuserForm.base_fields)
```

5) Override the RegistrationView. I'm not entirely sure why this is necessary, but I get errors without it. I believe it's saying, "Hey models, be prepared for an extra field".
This is basically copy/pasted from registration/backends/default/views.py, but with the
extra field added

```
# posts/views.py
from registration.backends.default.views import RegistrationView
from registration import signals
from registration.models import RegistrationProfile
from django.contrib.sites.models import Site
from django.contrib.sites.models import RequestSite

class CustomRegistrationView(RegistrationView):
    """
    Needed override this django-registration feature to have it create
    a profile with extra field
    """
    def register(self, request, **cleaned_data):
        username, email, password, user_type = cleaned_data['username'], cleaned_data['email'], cleaned_data['password1'], cleaned_data['user_type']
        if Site._meta.installed:
            site = Site.objects.get_current()
        else:
            site = RequestSite(request)
        new_user = RegistrationProfile.objects.create_inactive_user(
            username, email, password, user_type, site)
        signals.user_registered.send(sender=self.__class__,
                                     user=new_user,
                                     request=request)
    return new_user
```

6) Update the model. I did this by directly editing the django-registration model (since it's a lone-wolf project and this is my only use of it), but DO NOT do this if you are using django-registration for anything else. You could try overriding the model in your app I reckon. Anyways, in registration/models.py I added the extra field:

```
# registration/models.py
def create_inactive_user(self, username, email, password, user_type,
                         site, send_email=True):
    """
    Create a new, inactive ``User``, generate a
    ``RegistrationProfile`` and email its activation key to the
    ``User``, returning the new ``User``.

    By default, an activation email will be sent to the new
    user. To disable this, pass ``send_email=False``.

    """
    new_user = get_user_model().objects.create_user(username, email, password, user_type=user_type)
    new_user.is_active = False
    new_user.save()

    registration_profile = self.create_profile(new_user)

    if send_email:
        registration_profile.send_activation_email(site)

    return new_user
```

7) Update you urls file:

```
#appName/urls.py
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^accounts/register/$', CustomRegistrationView.as_view(
    form_class=RegistrationForm)),
)
```

Hopefully somebody, somewhere gets some use out of this. Happy Django-ing!

Answer (score 2):

It seems that step 3 in chipperdrew's answer is not necessary any more. I found that django-registration's code already incorporates the steps to import get_user_model(). This is true for django-registration v1.0

In registration/models.py, line 15-19

```
try:
    from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
    User = get_user_model()
except ImportError:
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User
```

Note: I can't seem to directly comment on chipperdrew's answer so I posted the above as a separate answer.