# how to change default django-registration Model used in its form?

Tags: django, django-models, django-registration

`django-registration` use `auth User` model in its form, but i want to use,

```
class Person( User ):
  dob    = models.DateField('Date of Birth', blank=True, null=True)
  ssn    = models.CharField(max_length=16, null=True, blank=True)
  tag    = models.ManyToManyField( PersonTags, related_name="tags" )
  parent = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True, related_name='children')
```

when user registers, it should go to Person and User models,  so now how can i do it in `django-registration`.

Please help me and thanx in advance :)

Comment: have a look at - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2601487/django-registration-django-profile-using-your-own-custom-form - explains how to customize the form with a custom backend.