# Creating a Django Registration Form by Extending Django-Registation Application

Tags: python, django, django-registration

Am trying to create a registration form by extending django-registration app and using Django Profile. I have created the model and form for the profile and when I checked through the django shell it is generating the fields. For the profile fields i am using ModelForm. Now I am struck on how to bring both the django-registration and the profile fields together. Following are the code i have developed

model.py

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    """
    This class would define the extra fields that is required for a user who will be registring to the site. This model will
    be used for the Django Profile Application
    """
    GENDER_CHOICES = ( 
        ('M', 'Male'),
        ('F', 'Female'),
    )

    #Links to the user model and will have one to one relationship
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)    

    #Other fields thats required for the registration
    first_name = models.CharField(_('First Name'), max_length = 50, null = False)    
    last_field = models.CharField(_('Last Name'),max_length = 50)
    gender = models.CharField(_('Gender'), max_length = 1, choices=GENDER_CHOICES, null = False)    
    dob = models.DateField(_('Date of Birth'), null = False)    
    country = models.OneToOneField(Country)
    user_type = models.OneToOneField(UserType)
    address1 = models.CharField(_('Street Address Line 1'), max_length = 250, null = False)
    address2 = models.CharField(_('Street Address Line 2'), max_length = 250)
    city = models.CharField(_('City'), max_length = 100, null = False)
    state = models.CharField(_('State/Province'), max_length = 250, null = False)
    pincode = models.CharField(_('Pincode'), max_length = 15)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField()
    updated_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

forms.py

```
class UserRegistrationForm(RegistrationForm, ModelForm):

    #resolves the metaclass conflict
    __metaclass__ = classmaker()

    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_field', 'gender', 'dob', 'country', 'user_type', 'address1', 'address2', 'city', 'state', 'pincode')
```

Now what should i do to mix django-registration app with my custom app. I had gone through lots of sites and links to figure it out including [Django-Registration & Django-Profile, using your own custom form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2601487/django-registration-django-profile-using-your-own-custom-form) but i am not sure to move forward especially since i am using ModelForm instead.

### UPDATE (26th Sept, 2011)

I made the changes as suggested by @VascoP below. I updated template file and then from my view.py  i created the following code

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':        
        form = UserRegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            UserRegistrationForm.save()
    else:
        form = UserRegistrationForm()
    return render_to_response('registration/registration_form.html',{'form' : form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

After the following change the form is correctly getting rendered but the problem is that the data is not getting saved. Please help me.

### UPDATE (27th Sept, 2011)

UserRegistrationForm.save() was changed to form.save(). The updated code is for views.py is as follows

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':        
        form = UserRegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
    else:
        form = UserRegistrationForm()
    return render_to_response('registration/registration_form.html',{'form' : form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Even after the update the user is not getting saved. Instead I am getting an error

> 'super' object has no attribute 'save'

I can see that there is no save method in RegistrationForm class. So what should i do now to save the data? Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are aware that the User model already has first_name and last_name fields, right? Also, you misstyped last_name to last_field.

I would advise to extend the form provided by django-registration and making a new form that adds your new fields. You can also save the first name and last name directly to the User model.

```
#get the form from django-registration
from registration.forms import RegistrationForm

class MyRegistrationForm(RegistrationForm):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length = 50, label=u'First Name')    
    last_field = models.CharField(max_length = 50, label=u'Last Name')
    ...
    pincode = models.CharField(max_length = 15, label=u'Pincode')


    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        new_user = super(MyRegistrationForm, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

        #put them on the User model instead of the profile and save the user
        new_user.first_name = self.cleaned_data['first_name']
        new_user.last_name = self.cleaned_data['last_name']
        new_user.save()

        #get the profile fields information
        gender = self.cleaned_data['gender']
        ...
        pincode = self.cleaned_data['pincode']

        #create a new profile for this user with his information
        UserProfile(user = new_user, gender = gender, ..., pincode = pincode).save()

        #return the User model
        return new_user
```

Comment: Thanks @VascoP for your help and sorry for the delay in responding. I have made the changes as you suggested and am able to render the form correctly. But still i am not able to save the data. Could you please check my UPDATED post above and help me? Thanks

Comment: You should do `form.save()` instead of `UserRegistrationForm.save()`

Comment: Thanks will check and revert back :)

Comment: Did this solve your problem or is there another reason you didn't mark as answered?

Comment: Well there is an error that am getting now 
'super' object has no attribute 'save'
Checked the RegistrationForm and I could not find a save() method in it. Please help me

Comment: Are you sure you have replaced "MyRegistrationForm" with your "UserRegistrationForm" in the code?