# Extending Django-Registration: Getting error on setting url.py

Tags: python, django, django-registration

am trying to follow the answers provided in [Django-Registration & Django-Profile, using your own custom form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2601487/django-registration-django-profile-using-your-own-custom-form) and [Creating a Django Registration Form by Extending Django-Registation Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7447522/creating-a-django-registration-form-by-extending-django-registation-application) to extend the django-registration form. I added the following code in url.py

```
url(r'^accounts/register/$', register, {'backend': 'registration.backends.default.DefaultBackend','form_class': UserRegistrationForm}, name='registration_register'),
(r'^accounts/', include(regUrls)),
```

but now whenever i access http://localhost:8000/accounts/register/ am getting the following error

> register() got an unexpected keyword argument 'form_class'

Please help me out. Why am i getting this error? I goggled a lot but still i could not figure out a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That dictionary in your urls.py entry gets passed as keyword arguments to the view function, `register`, when you access the page.  `register` doesn't have a keyword argument `form_class`.

If the `register` your first link is referring to is the `register` from the second, the first link is wrong.  Because that `register` doesn't accept that keyword arg.  [One answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2601487/django-registration-django-profile-using-your-own-custom-form/3298481#3298481) seems to define a different register method, but I think that might be something else(?)

If you understand what the `form_class` is supposed to be passed to, you could just add the kwarg to `register` manually too.

Comment: Thanks Dave, as i said i was just following the posts i have provided above and in there they had given the URL like this. Am very new to django so kind of confused on what needs to be done. So could you tell me how i can fix this issue? Thanks

Comment: @swaroop sorry if I wasn't clear.  The actual *problem* is that django is calling `register(request, backend = registration.backends.default.DefaultBackend, form_class= UserRegistrationForm)`, but the function `register` is defined as `def register(request):`.  It doesn't know how to take those keyword arguments.  Unfortunately *I* don't understand what's going on in these posts either, so I can't tell you exactly what was supposed to happen there.  But maybe this is somewhere to start.

Comment: Dave your previous comment itself helped me to solve the issue. It was just that I was not importing the register method from registration.views and after doing that it got solved. Thanks a lot for helping me