# customise form-fields of django-registration utilising the simple.backend

Tags: django, django-registration

I am using the django registratations.backends.simple.urls and I want to add a customised field in my registration page

The simple.backend is different from the default.backend as it's lightweight and doesn't require user verification configurations("smtp, email, etc")

models.py

```
from registration.signals import user_registered
from django.dispatch import receiver

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, unique=True, primary_key=True, related_name="user")
    # Extra attributes
    bio = models.TextField(null=True)
    country = models.ForeignKey(Countries, null=True)

@receiver(user_registered)
def registration_active_country(sender, user, request, **kwargs):
    print >> sys.stderr , request.POST['country']
    funid = request.POST['country']
    a = Countries.objects.get(pk=funid)
    userid = user.id
    user = UserProfile.objects.get(pk=userid)
    user.country = a
    user.save()
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^accounts/register/$', register, {'backend': 'registration.backends.simple.SimpleBackend','form_class': UserRegistrationForm}, name='registration_register'),


url(r'^accounts/', include("registration.backends.simple.urls")),
```

forms.py

```
class UserRegistrationForm(RegistrationForm):
    country = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Countries.objects, label=u'Country', empty_label=u'Not defined')
```

is there a better answer?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2601487/django-registration-django-profile-using-your-own-custom-form

Comment: Did it, will be updating the solution soon. This is not a duplicate as this utilises the Simple.urls as compared to the other post which utilises the Default.Urls

Comment: What was the difference between the two solutions? Just the config in urls.py or something more?

Comment: you are right, the main difference is in urls.py however I utilised the the user_registered signal as compared to the accepted solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

models.py

```
from registration.signals import user_registered
from django.dispatch import receiver

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, unique=True, primary_key=True, related_name="user")
    # Extra attributes
    bio = models.TextField(null=True)
    country = models.ForeignKey(Countries, null=True)

@receiver(user_registered)
def registration_active_country(sender, user, request, **kwargs):
    print >> sys.stderr , request.POST['country']
    funid = request.POST['country']
    a = Countries.objects.get(pk=funid)
    userid = user.id
    user = UserProfile.objects.get(pk=userid)
    user.country = a
    user.save()
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^accounts/register/$', register, {'backend': 'registration.backends.simple.SimpleBackend','form_class': UserRegistrationForm}, name='registration_register'),


url(r'^accounts/', include("registration.backends.simple.urls")),
```

forms.py

```
class UserRegistrationForm(RegistrationForm):
    country = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Countries.objects, label=u'Country', empty_label=u'Not defined')
```