# Using custom forms in Django instead of modifying the source files

Tags: python, django, django-forms, overriding, django-registration

Let me preface this by saying I'm VERY new to Django and am also having a hard time with some of the documentation. I know that this question has surely been asked and answered a thousand times, but I can't seem to phrase my query properly.

I'm making a project that uses django-registration-redux, and I wanted to customize the template and the forms to accept additional user information. First, I noticed that my changes to the template files weren't having any effect , then I realized that it was using the template files from my Python install location instead of my actual project. I fixed this by setting the templates folder setting, but I also need to modify the registration-redux forms, and can't figure out how to override the default forms with local forms in my application.

Answer (score 0):

You need not change the template settings for your existing project, but you have to make sure you have included 'registration' in the list of your INSTALLED_APPS. In the documentation its mentioned that

`You can extend and customize the included templates as needed`

Though its not very clear here, django registration redux is built on top of the in built django registration module. What you need to do is build your own custom registration form which is already explained in [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2601487/5340798)

In your case the template that you need to modify/extend is `registration/registration_form.html`.

Other useful resources that can help you:

http://www.tangowithdjango.com/book17/chapters/login_redux.html
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qkFWkOw-ByU