# Create additional model on activation django-registration

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin, django-registration

I have been struggling with implementing different answers to handle (e.g. [Django-Registration & Django-Profile, using your own custom form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2601487/django-registration-django-profile-using-your-own-custom-form/14834740#14834740)) but have not managed to get this to work in my project because it seems too out of date.

Essentially I have installed Django-Registration in my project and can have the User authenticated and created via this.

However, I have extended the User with the following UserProfile model:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    account_type = models.IntegerField(null = True, default= 1)
    daily_message = models.BooleanField(default = True)
    tel_number = models.CharField(max_length=20, null = True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user)
```

And I would like that either:

1. UserProfile with default/null values is created for each user
   (user can update this later)
2. User is able to enter a telephone
   number with other details on registration.

The following is hooked up in my URLs.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^accounts/', include('registration.backends.hmac.urls')),
    url(r'^', include('app.urls'))
]
```

As I have no visibility over any of the Django-registration forms and a lot of the documentation describes a custom user model (which I do not have), any ideas how I could do one of the above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are lot's of different ways in which this task can be achieved the most django like method would be to rely on a signal. More specifically the [user_registered](https://django-registration.readthedocs.io/en/2.1.1/signals.html#registration.signals.user_registered) signal.

> registration.signals.user_registered Sent when a new user account is
>   registered. Provides the following arguments:
>
> **sender** The RegistrationView subclass used to register the account.
>   **user** A user-model instance representing the new account.
>   **request** The
>   HttpRequest in which the new account was registered.

```
def create_user_profile(sender, user, requet):
    '''
    Creates a profile object for registered users via the
    user_registered signal
    '''

    obj = UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
```

An alternative is to subclass the [RegistrationView](https://django-registration.readthedocs.io/en/2.1.1/views.html#registration.views.RegistrationView). A second alternative is to catch the post_save signal on User.